# Auto-Running Code in VS Code Terminal / Powershell

Tags: python, windows, powershell, visual-studio-code

I'm coding in Python. I'm having to debug a script and run the same line of code dozens of times per day. I have VS Code set up so that it automatically enters my virtual environment ever time I open the terminal:

```
(base) PS C:\SomeFolder> conda activate some_env
```

I set that up in the settings.json file for Windows shell with "python.pythonPath".

Is there any way to run additional lines of code automatically? For instance, after VS Code enters my virtual environment, is there a way I could get it to automatically do something like this:

```
(some_env) PS: C:\SomeFolder> python SomeProgram.py
```

So now it enters my virtual environment and runs my program automatically?

Comment: You can set up a Powershell profile and add any code you like.

Comment: You could also set up a command to send text to the terminal; see the [terminal docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal) for details. But why don't you just set up a debug configuration so you just have to hit F5 to debug your app?